# System.Diagnostics.Activity threw an exception

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My reports were working like a charm until yesterday. But after un-installing and installing again these Nugets packages i.e. Jquery, Bootstrap, Microsoft reporting service control web and others, it not working any more. Although i can build and display new reports but not able to view the old ones. Could you please give me some hint to fix these. I am using visual studio 2017, sql server 2016.

This is the exact error

> An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation.The type initializer for
>   'System.Diagnostics.Activity' threw an exception.Operation could
>   destabilize the runtime.

Thanks,

Ghaffar

Comment: This error occurs only when I paste built-in parameters in the rdlc report in visual studio 2017 community. Others wise the report runs. I still can't find a way around.